# Dynamically adding container to a dynamic container

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a loop that goes through data from a book and displays it. The book is not consistent in it's layout so I am trying to display it in two different ways. First way(works fine) is to load the text from that section in to a panel and display it. The second way is to create a new panel (panel creates fine) and then add collapsable panels(nested) to that panel. Here is the code from the else loop.

```
else if (newPanel == false){
                    // simpleData is just for  the title bar of the new panel
                    // otherwise the panel has no content
                    var simpleData:Section = new Section;
                    simpleData.section_letter = item.section_letter;
                    simpleData.letter_title = item.letter_title;
                    simpleData.section_id = item.section_id;
                    simpleData.title = item.title;
                    simpleData.bookmark = item.bookmark;
                    simpleData.read_section = item.read_section;

                    var display2:readPanel02 = new readPanel02;
                    //item is all the data for the new text
                    display2.id = "panel"+item.section_id;
                    //trace(display2.name);//trace works fine
                    // set vars is how I pass in the data to the panel
                    display2.setVars(simpleData);
                    studyArea.addElement(display2); // displays fine
                    newPanel = true;

                    //this is where it fails
                    var ssPanel:subSectionPanel = new subSectionPanel;
                    //function to pass in the vars to the new panel
                    ssPanel.setSSVars(item);
                    //this.studyArea[newPanelName].addElement(ssPanel);
                    this["panel"+item.section_id].addElement(ssPanel);
```

The error I get is: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property panel4.4 not found on components.readTest and there is no default value.

I have tried setting the "name" property instead of the "id" property. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am stumped. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  You just want to display the book data?  Don't concentrate on the how, but the what. From a glance at your code I can tell you that what you're doing is far from optimal.

Comment: @J_A_X I don't know if you saw I answered it myself. What do you think about the code there? I know very little about optimal, so I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: Again, I can't comment because I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with all this.  What's the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @J_A_X The text is from a book. The book is vary inconsistent. Some sections are only a paragraph and some are 15 pages. For the ones that are 15 pages I am breaking them into subsections and displaying each subsection into a collapsable panel for easier navigation. The code is supposed to 1.get the results back from a sql call 2.loop through the results to decide how to display them  3.Sections are displayed in the appropriate panel. As I said above I did figure it out (below). Just wanted the input of someone who knows more than me since you pointed out how un-optimal it was. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of navigation? What's the behavior when displaying the book or moving to the next section?  Is there a reason this can't be done using TLF textfield linking between "pages"?

Comment: @J_A_X The book is approx 1000 pages long, and there are quizzes and flashcards associated with every section. The user 1. decides what chapter to study 2. If he/she wants to read, see flashcards, or quiz.3 There are submenus for each choice. I am still entering the text into my database, but I am splitting it up into sections so if a user wants to read the text that a question was based off of it would be a simple call. Now that I've written this I feel I've gone way off subject, I will look into textfield linking. Thanks for your time, any other suggestions?

Comment: I can't comment further without seeing the UX designs.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I came up with. I made the new readPanel create the sub panels. I added the else statement to help it make more sense. The readPanel creates the first sub panel, and for every subsequent need of a sub panel it references the other panel by name and calls the public function in the panel that creates the new sub panel. Here's the code to create the main panel:

```
else if (newPanel == false){
                    var display2:readPanel02 = new readPanel02;
                    studyArea.addElement(display2);
                    display2.name = "panel"+item.section_id;
                    display2.setVars(item);

                    newPanel = true;

                }
                else{
                    var myPanel:readPanel02 = studyArea.getChildByName("panel"+item.section_id) as readPanel02;
                    myPanel.addSubSection(item);

                }
```

And here is the functions in the panel:

```
public function setVars(data:Section):void
        {
            myS = data;
            textLetter = myS.section_letter;
            textLetterTitle = myS.letter_title;
            textSection = myS.section_id;
            textTitle = myS.title;
            myS.bookmark == 0 ? bookmarked = false : bookmarked = true;
            myS.read_section == 0 ? doneRead = false : doneRead = true;
            showTagIcon();
            showReadIcon();
            addSubSection(myS);

        }

        public function addSubSection(data:Section):void{
            var ssPanel:subSectionPanel = new subSectionPanel;
            ssPanel.setSSVars(data);
            myContentGroup.addElementAt(ssPanel, i);
            i++;
        }
```